# How to upload 2D image in website?

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I want to Upload 2D image into My Website,and my requirements are like below
I can change all Dimension of that image like i can change Hight,weight,color or many more. and i want to take Sketchup file as a image. please tell me how to do this thing.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you tried? What research did you do prior to asking this question?

Comment: I have search that whether is it possible using ruby ?or any other language. i dont know how to do this. i am trying to find solution of this task

Comment: You want to create a SketchUp plugin that will export a 2D image of the current viewport and upload to a webserver?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to do this in Ruby?

Read this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Martin Velez My I Add sketchup File

Comment: Yes, you can upload any type of file.  After you upload, your web application must do something with the file (display, store, alter, etc.).